# how do i use batchGet() to fetch tow tables

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am trying to fetch two tables using batch Get().

```
Error { ResourceNotFoundException: Requested resource not found
    at Request.extractError (D: \Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\json.js:51:27)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (D:\Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (D: \Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (D: \Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (D: \Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at D: \Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (D:\Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Posts\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message: 'Requested resource not found',
  code: 'ResourceNotFoundException',
  time: 2019-09-23T07:29:13.128Z,
  requestId: 'VVSRDL4V2299JSMFKD88R8TT77VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 24.23023597884083 }
```

Comment: Post the code what you have tried, so that its easy to debug..

Comment: docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
var params = {
    "RequestItems": {
        "Table": { tableName1,
            "Keys": [   
            {
              // "column_name":{"S":"Primary Key"}
           }
           ],
        }
        "TableTwo": { tableName2,
            "Keys": [
                 {
                   // "column_name":{"S":"Primary Key"}
              },
          ]
    }

};
docClient.batchGet(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});

Comment: adding code here on stack overflow is very difficult.

Comment: Check again your table name.